# Can I make firefox configuration changes without restarting the browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to perform some changes in about:config by running a javascript without requiring me to restart the browser.

**EDIT:**
I'm asking about dynamci change by running a javascript. I do not want to make different profiles.

Comment: No, you can't  do that

Comment: If you mean somehow hacking it, its no way doing that. Before you could ask the user to change the configs like asking for geolocation by now its avoided in ff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple configurations and you can use them simultaneously with restarting any browser instance.  Set up multiple profiles and then you're done.  If you only ever need to switch between a few possible configurations then it's a viable answer.  But if you're asking about dynamically changing configurations to arbitrary values at runtime I wouldn't know.

Comment: U mean somehow hack it?